# How to find the distance between places

Tags: javascript, asp.net, distance

I am having 4 textboxes which are textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4. The end user will put 4 locations in each textbox like place1, place2, place3, place4. I need to display the distance between the places in the following order:

1. Distance between palace1 and place2:
2. Distance between palace2 and place3:
3. Distance between palace3 and place4:

How to do this? I have taken help of the following link:
http://briancray.com/2009/04/01/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api/
It helps when only two textbox are there.But I was unable to solve my problem.Solutions are expected using Javascript or Jquery or ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: What information is being provided to identify the places - e.g. post code / long-lat?  You say the link doesn't solve your problem,  but it appears to answer the question you're asking - so why doesn't it solve your problem?  Are you talking about straight line distance or the distance via road?  The number of text boxes shouldn't be relevant should it?  You just repeat the calculation several times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [this](http://www.sudhirhub.com/2010/05/find-distance-between-two-cities-using.html) for JQuery not exact answer but you can modify. And want to manipulate in C# so you can use [this](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.cs.html) for getting from longitude and latitude and get longitude and latitude from the [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/) free DB (this one is if you don't want to use relay API)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the geographic coordinates for each location, and then use the Haversine formula to calculate the approximate distance between them.

Alternately, you might pass the addresses to a service like Google Maps and use the API to get the distance between the two addresses. The problem with using Google Maps is that you have a limited hit count.

Take a look at this article:
http://www.ig.utexas.edu/outreach/googleearth/latlong.html